Article omission before Anfang/Ende
I have always said:

vor/nach dem Anfang etwas ("etwas" in genitive)


vor/nach dem Ende etwas ("etwas" in genitive)

But I noticed lately in the news those are not common. For instance, at 00:25 and at 8:20 of https://www.tagesschau.de/multimedia/sendung/tagesschau_20_uhr/video-1391804.html, the news presenter says:

Kurz vor Ende seiner Amtszeit, ...


Es gibt keine Strategie für den Tag nach Ende des Krieges.

Are those the most usual constructs in informal German too?
I assume this is also valid for similar words like "Mittel", i.e. "vor Mitte seiner Amtszeit", "vor Mitte des Krieges" ?

Yes, omitting the article in front of Anfang, Mitte, Ende is acceptable. In some cases it's more common, and in some even mandatory.
A bit of background: The most typical use of Anfang, Mitte, Ende is in front of either a year or a month, like in Anfang 1955, Mitte September, Ende Juli 2012. But it is also possible to combine it with other time spans, like Anfang KW 31 (KW stands for Kalenderwoche, week of the year) or Ende der 90er.
It is remarkable that these can be used on their own, even if the base time span can't. While you can say Anfang der 90er Jahre wohnte er hier, you can't say 90er Jahre wohnte er hier. Using an article here is not possible. While Anfang des 21. Jahrhunderts is a time span, am Anfang des 21. Jahrhunderts feels more like the time point, the literal beginning. So Merkel war Anfang des 21. Jahrhunderts Kanzlerin. is correct, while Am Anfang des 21. Jahrhunderts war Merkel Kanzlerin would raise eyebrows.
When used with a year or month, the month is not in genitive, so not Anfang Mais. This makes the construction intransparent, so much that some speakers use the proscribed "Anfang diese Woche" in analogy, as evidenced here. The rule is, as always with genitive, messy: If you have a determiner to mark it, use genitive.
If you can't mark genitive, like in Anfang 1999, you can never use an article. Even if you can mark it, when used with time spans, not using an article is common.
Now take all these messy rules and try to apply them to events. It seems both using an article and not using one is common. Just compare hits for "vor [dem] Ende der zweiten Halbzeit" in Google or DWDS hits for "vor #1 Anfang des" or "vor #1 Ende des".


Kurz vor dem Ende seiner Amtszeit, ...


Es gibt keine Strategie für den Tag nach dem Ende des Krieges.

That dem is required. You can only leave it out for proper nouns e.g

Es gibt keine Strategie für den Tag nach Weihnachten.

But Ende seiner Amtszeit and Ende des Krieges aren't proper nouns so they made a mistake. It's common though.

Interesting that those are acceptable. Analogous errors in English (i.e. "before/after end..." without the article "the" before "end")  would be very badly seen in English-speaking news.

They aren't really acceptable but the people in German mass media typically aren't the brightest candles on the cake.

I don't agree that it is wrong. I also couldn't find any authoritative sources on the Nullartikel, especially for this case. It didn't strike me as unusual or wrong at all. And if the Tagesschau can't be trusted for the quality of its spoken German, who can?

@Raketenolli: Probably not sufficiently authoritative, bit mentions Anfang/Mitte/Ende explicitly : https://der-artikel.de/nullartikel.html.
